# Is the supremum norm the only $ C^{*} $-norm on $ {C_{c}}(X) $, equipped with the usual pointwise operations?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $ X $ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Then $ {C_{c}}(X) $ is a *commutative* $ * $-algebra with respect to addition, multiplication, scalar multiplication and conjugation (all pointwise operations).

> **Question.** If $ \| \cdot \|: {C_{c}}(X) \to \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0} $ is a (not-necessarily-complete) $ C^{*} $-norm on this $ * $-algebra, then is it true that $ \| \cdot \| $ is actually the supremum norm on $ {C_{c}}(X) $? If so, then $ {C_{0}}(X) $ is the only $ C^{*} $-completion of this $ * $-algebra.

This question seemed trivial at first sight, but after a while, I realized that it was not at all.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The norm on a C*-álgebra is determined by the algebra structure, no?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: Indeed, $||x||^2$ is the spectral radius of $x x^*$

Comment: Yes, it is. If $ {C_{c}}(X) $ is *complete* with respect to a $ C^{\ast} $-norm, then that $ C^{\ast} $-norm is unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be some C$^*$-norm on $C_c(X)$. Write $A=(C_0 (X),\|\cdot\|_\infty) $, $B=\overline {C_c(X),\|\cdot\|) }$.

Fix $f_0\in C_c(X)$. Put $A_0=C^*(f_0)\subset A$, and $\pi:A_0\to B$ the identity map (this works because  $A_0\subset C_c (X)\subset B $; since we use the supremum norm to generate it, every element has support inside that of $f_0$).

As $\pi$ is a $*$-monomorphism it is isometric, and thus $\|f_0\|=\|f_0\|_\infty$.

Comment: I admit, I didn't expect such a simple and elegant answer.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for the solution. I can accept this one. :)